# Is it possible to store XSLT code in XML element?

Tags: xml, xslt, apache-fop

What I want to do is execute some xslfo code from xml node for example :

XML :

```
<element>
  <fo:table>
    <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
             <fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:block>
                       blablabalba
                  </fo:block>
             </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
  </fo:table>
</element>
```

XSL :

```
 <fo:block>
      <xsl:value-of select="element"/>
 </fo:block>
```

Is that possible ?

Note : If I try it, it output the code stored in XML as text, is there a tag or something that would allow me to execute that code instead of printing it ?

Answer (score 0):

`<xsl:copy-of select="element/node()"/>`

This will copy all of the node children of the element child.  What you were asking for is the text value of the element child.

Now, as for copying an XSL-FO table to be a child of a block, I'm surprised to see that ... it isn't something that I teach in the classroom.  A table is already a block-level construct, so I'm unsure why you would want to put it into a block.

Comment: I've already tried your method before, however the code is escaped and is printed on the page instead of being executed. + Copying it into a block is an example, is it supposed to works or it is impossible ?

Comment: Inspect the XSL-FO after you have transformed it to see how the element markup is escaped, because otherwise it would not be printed on the page.  `<xsl:copy-of/>` does not perform any escaping.

Comment: There is no fault with putting a table inside of a block, it is just redundant unless, perhaps, you were using the block to wrap a number of block-level constructs (but then I would ask "why?").

Comment: The element containing the xslfo code is generated in java maybe that's why ?

I use :

    node.setTextContent("my xslfo code here");

And I return the node which I retrieve from xsl file

Comment: I don't know your library but "setTextContent" tells me to translate the content into text, not into markup.  Is there a reason you aren't creating only XML using Java and use XSLT to create all of your XSL-FO?

Comment: Yea there is a reason, and I also realized that setTextContent translate into text, however if I try with setNodeValue there is simply nothing that print

What I'm trying to do is replace <ul> and <li> tag found in some xml with fop code then retrieve that code from xsl

Comment: I'm stepping away from this because I'm unfamiliar with your Java interface.  You tagged this question XSLT, not Java.  XSLT is manifestly XML, while XML is an afterthought for Java ... I suggest you do the XML work in XSLT.  Good luck!